# how to create cms from scratch using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm thinking of building my own CMS but I'm not that professional in PHP,

More advanced in asp.net

So if anyone knows the basics steps or has a tutorial for that I'll be thankful.

Regards,

Comment: This needs a lot of conversation. Is not so simple. On my opinion, of course.

Comment: Just start coding and ask a question here when you have a specific programming problem.

Comment: Get some experience with existing CMs and reproduce what you like about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you give Microsoft's blogengine a try?

You can find it at http://www.dotnetblogengine.net

They gave it a very nice site with lots of content on how to build your own asp.net blog-style cms. From there, you should be able to work your way to your very own engine.